# retaining when returning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Should I be retaining the responseData that I am returning

```
// METHOD
-(NSData *)dataFromTurbine:(NSString *)pathToURL {

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:pathToURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                                 returningResponse:&response 
                                                             error:&error];

    [request release];
    [url release];
    return responseData;
}
```

.

```
// CALLED
NSData *newData = dataFromTurbine(kTurbineDataPath);
[doSomething newData];
```

Comment: If you're using Xcode, use Build & Analyze, this will help you a lot with this stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the method name doesn't start with `init`, `new` or `copy`, `dataFromTurbine` should return an autoreleased instance of NSData. (Which is already true now for responseData)

The calling method then has ownership, and should retain if needed.

Comment: Much appreciated Rengers, I was getting mixed up, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no.

The NSData object you get from NSURLConnection is autoreleased, so you should retain/release it only if you need to keep it. Otherwise, it will be automatically released for you at the next pass of the run loop.